# Extracting fields from a json file

Tags: python, json

I am provided with the following json file.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "useless_field1": null,
      "useless_field2": null,
      "data": [
        {
          "type": "type_1",
          "useless_field3": null,
          "volumne": "5"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to extract only the following fields: `id, type, volume`. I did it in the following way.

```
def extract(json_response):
    return [{
        item['id'],
        item['data'][0]['type'],
        item['data'][0]['volume']
    } for item in json_response['results']]
```

It is possible for the `type` to be a list. Is my solution efficient? Are there any alternatives of solving such problems?

Comment: You're returning a list of sets, it may be not what you actually want.

Comment: You need to expand the JSON sample to include an edge case, and you need to write down the expected output for that edge case (i.e., what if it actually *is* a list?)

Comment: Hi @Hendra, don't worry about "efficient"... this is plenty efficient enough. But think about whether these fields are guaranteed to be present (you'll get an error if they are not), and see if you like the format of the results you produce.